# JavaScript won't change my color when it should, and also weird log. appears

Tags: javascript, dom

So I wanted to code a simple project. When a button is clicked, the program generates a random number between 1 and 50 and then prints it inside my DIV.
I wanted a little feature that if the number happens to be 18, the background color changes to red.

So I've tried do do this many times, but the background changing randomly. No order or whatsoever.

I've tried to log the numbers, to see is there any connection between the them when it changing to red, but no luck.

However, in the console, a little grey `2` appears. Also at random times.

```
function getRandomNumber(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + 1;
    return randomNumber;
}
myButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    para.innerHTML = getRandomNumber();
    console.log(getRandomNumber());
    if(getRandomNumber() === 18){
        para.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
```

Comment: You're calling `getRandomNumber` 3 times (I guess you're expecting it to return the same number). Store the return value in a variable `var theNumber = getRandomNumber();` and use that variable instead of recalling it. And I suggest that you add an `else` to that `if` in case the color is already red, and the number is not 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call `getRandomNumber()` it's generating a new number.  Call it once, save it to a variable, and everything should work as you expect.

```
function getRandomNumber() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
  return randomNumber;
}
myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let number = getRandomNumber();
  para.innerHTML = number;
  console.log(number);
  if (number === 18) {
    para.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set return value of `getRandomNumber()` as a variable. Toggle `backgroundColor` between `"red"` and `"unset"` or empty string `""`

```js
function getRandomNumber(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4) + 1;
  return randomNumber;
}

var para = document.querySelector("p");
var myButton = document.querySelector("button");

myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 const rand = getRandomNumber();
 para.innerHTML = rand;
 para.style.backgroundColor = rand === 1 ? "red" : "unset";
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your issue is that you are calling `getRandomNumber` twice, which will get you two different random numbers. Save the random number to a variable `var randomNumber = getRandomNumber()` and then use this variable to set the innerHTML of your para and check if it's eighteen to see if the background should change.
2. The grey number 2 just means that the same number is being printed twice in a row.